# Java I think my question is How can I reuse an object to add 2 records into my database program

Tags: java, object, new-operator, reusability

First use of validUser works perfectly
Second attempt with new names fails!

```
// First use of validUser works perfectly
username = "Fred";
password ="Flintstone";
User validUser = new User(username,password);
data.add(validUser);
System.out.println("Successful!");  

// Second attempt with new names fails! 
username = "John";
password = "doe";

User validUser = new User(username,password);
// ERROR: variable validUser is already defined    
// I just want to put two records into the DB.
// Can't I (or how can I)  just reuse validUser?
// I tried to take "new" out but that didn't work either. Thanks!

data.add(validUser);
```

Comment: The second time, you don't need to declare validUser as a User. Just use the line 'validUser = new User(username,password);'

Comment: **or** `data.add(new User("John", "doe"));` - the temporary local variables don't seem to add much value. **Maybe** `data.addAll(Arrays.asList(new User("Fred", "Flintstone"), new User("John", "doe")));` - why use ten lines of code, when one will do?

Comment: Replace the second `User validUser = new User(username,password);` with `validUser = new User(username,password);`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reuse the same variable just reassign the reference.
`validUser = new User(...);`

By preceding the data type is like you want to declare the same variable twice in the same scope -> forbidden.

By the way avoid this kind of variable reassignment.It is error prone and decreases the readability of the code( prefer immutable variable). 
Just declare new ones or not declare at all by inline them where there are needed. Like this.
`data.add(new User());`

Comment: Yes! Thank you for your time. I played around with that line of code after taking a break and my next guess worked.